# How can I convert lots of ASCII files (.xyz format) into shapefiles by iterator in the Modelbuilder of Arcgis 10?

Tags: modelbuilder

I have a plethora of xyz format files and I want to convert them into shapefiles separately and it is really time-consuming to do this conversion one by one.

I tried to create a model in ModelBuilder to read them from an input folder and does the conversion into shapefiles and then put them into the output folder with the same input name or use a wildcard to choose some of them to convert.

---

[image]

However, the files that I'm trying to convert are
XYZ foramt (e.g. file.xyz) ASCII files. Anyway, I used the following model to convert the files in the folder and what it really does is just converting the first file and then stops. I also ticked on the Recursive but it only converts the first file and stops.

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Have you looked at incorporating the Iterate Files option, http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Files/00400000000v000000/?

Comment: You note below you've got a model that works on a single file? As an alternative to just model builder you could export your model to a Python script and use a simple for... loop to iterate over your files (the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) library might help with making the file list). You can even put the script back into a toolbox if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. However, I finally managed to create a model for it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following model and it works pretty well.  The only inputs are the input folder where your .txt files are stored and the output folder.  The output .shp name is the same as your input .txt name.  Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually the files are with xyz format.

Comment: if you open your xyz ascii data, is the format similar to the following, with "x,y,z," as a header?: x,y,z,
838959.41800,4713239.59000,1.00000
841305.41800,4708452.59000,1.00000
839175.41800,...